# how to solve the undefined error in jquery radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the value of three radio buttons. I have 3 form fields.

`$('input[name=optradio]:checked').val();` provides the correct answer. However,

`$('.listing_type input:radio:checked').val();` returns `undefined`.

How can I solve this?

```js
var listing=$('input[name=optradio]:checked').val();

console.log(listing);

var overwrite = $('.listing_type input:radio:checked').val();
alert(overwrite);
```

```php
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
$response = Array
(
    "0" => Array
        (
            "id" => "57fde39205dd7b0ef89e02e3",
            "name" => "SELL"
        ),

    "1" => Array
        (
            "id" => "57fde3aa05dd7b0ef89e02e4",
            "name" => "RENT"
        )

);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
echo "</pre>";
$count = count($response);
foreach($response as $res)
{
$property = "RENT";
?>
<input type="radio" name="optradio"  class="listing_type" value="<?php echo $res["name"];?>" 
    <?php 
    if($property==$res["name"])
    { 
    echo "checked=checked";
    }
    ?>><?php 
    $l_t=$res["name"];
    if($l_t == "SELL"){
        echo "Sell";
    }else{
        echo "Rent";
    }
    ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Are .listing_type and input two different elements?

Comment: Maybe `$res["name"]` is `undefined`?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
$('.listing_type:input:radio:checked').val();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body><pre>Array
(
    [0] =&gt; Array
        (
            [id] =&gt; 57fde39205dd7b0ef89e02e3
            [name] =&gt; SELL
        )

    [1] =&gt; Array
        (
            [id] =&gt; 57fde3aa05dd7b0ef89e02e4
            [name] =&gt; RENT
        )

)
</pre>
  <input type="radio" name="optradio" class="listing_type" value="SELL">Sell
  <input type="radio" name="optradio" class="listing_type" value="RENT" checked="checked">Rent

  <script>
    var listing = $('input[name=optradio]:checked').val();

    console.log(listing);

    var overwrite = $('.listing_type:input:radio:checked').val();
    alert(overwrite);
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`input.listing_type:radio:checked` should do the trick. You're using many kinds of selectors here: tagName `input`, className `listing_type`, jquery's form selector `:radio`, and the CSS3 selector `:checked`.